# Input numbers only but allow '-' at the beginning

Tags: jquery

I need to block input only for numbers. I also need to allow `-` only 1 time, and if present, only at beginning.

This is my script that work great now:

```
$('#sss').on('input', function() {
  this.value = this.value
    .replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '')             // numbers and decimals only and negative
    .replace(/(^[\d]{3})[\d]/g, '$1')   // not more than 3 digits at the beginning
    .replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1')         // decimal can't exist more than once
    .replace(/(\.[\d]{2})./g, '$1');    // not more than 2 digits after decimal
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jz60p7xn/1/

I don't know how to edit my code. Tried adding: `.replace(/(\-*)\./g, '$1')` without success.

So:

```
2.345 wrong
1234.43 wrong
2 ok
123.00 ok
-123.00 ok <--- attention at this cause i've set a number digit of 3 at beginning, so if "-" is present i don't know if rules works great
--2 wrong
2.00- wrong
23.-54 wrong
```

Comment: `input type="number" pattern="RegExpHere"` is not good enough?

Comment: The fiddle don't look like the code you posted here

Comment: Please do not use external code sites. StackOverflow has very good snippet functionality that is sufficient 99% of the times. Use that instead.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen sorry wrong link https://jsfiddle.net/jz60p7xn/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to go the string manipulation route, then you can match `-`s that are *not* at the beginning of the string with the pattern `(?!^)-`:

```
$('#sss').on('input', function() {
  this.value = this.value
    .replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '')            // numbers and decimals only and negative
    .replace(/(?!^)-/g, '')             // allow - only at the beginning
    .replace(/^(-?\d{3})\d+/, '$1')     // not more than 3 digits at the beginning
    .replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1')         // decimal can't exist more than once
    .replace(/(\.[\d]{2})./g, '$1');    // not more than 2 digits after decimal
});
```

Or, you could consider just using `<input type="number">`.

Comment: Thanks it work but.... 3 digits at the beginning rules broken in this case if - is present

Comment: Add an optional `-` to the beginning with `^-?`

Comment: Oh, you mean the `-` gets replaced? Put it inside the capturing group, instead of outside. (If that's not what you were referring to, can you explain what exactly the issue is?)